# sapui5 karma coverage don't support es6 syntax

Tags: ecmascript-6, sapui5, karma-coverage

In sapui5 , I want to run karma to test some file about es6 code.
But It can't be supported.

I try to join babel in karma.conf.js, transform the es6 code to es5 code ,then run coverage. It works fine, but the result is not normal. It tests the es5 code.

```
preprocessors: {
      'webapp/controller/*.js': ['babel', 'coverage']
      // './!(test|localService)/**/*.js': ['coverage']
    },

    babelPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        sourceMap: 'inline'
      },

      sourceFileName: function(file) {
        return file.originalPath;
      }
    }
```

I want to get the coverage about es6 code. But actually it gets the coverage of the es5 code。

Comment: How should I do ? I must to get the correct coverage.

Comment: This sounds like the preprocessed files are not loaded via the karma server. Can you share the full configuration or an example project?